# about .replace in Velocity

Tags: replace, velocity

I have a Pipe `|` delimited file I'm sending out and in a string field the client is using Pipes as just a random character to separate points.

Example. This is what text they have in the field.

```
Encore AWD | Leather | Navigation | Sunroof | Back Up Camera | USB | Bluetooth
```

I need to replace the | with a - and this is the code I'm trying.

```
#set ($va.list_comment = $va.listing_comment.replace("|", "-"))
```

it is still outputting the | characters.

Anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: If it's the normal Java `String.replace` then it's because it expects a regex, not a string. I'd try escaping the special character first and see if that works.

Comment: [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) works with regular expressions, [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) replaces plain text occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a new value into an object. If you're using the latest version of Velocity, then such an assignment would work **if** there is a `setList_comment` method, or if `$va` is a `Map`. Otherwise, you would have to just create a new variable that would host the new value and use it:

```
#set ($fixedListing = $va.listing_comment.replace("|", "-"))
$fixedListing
```

Or if you don't need that value for anything else than just printing it once, skip the assignment completely and just print the outcome:

```
$va.listing_comment.replace("|", "-")
```

If that still doesn't work, make sure the value returned is indeed a `java.lang.String` and not something else:

```
$va.listing_comment.class
```